# Pause video progress bar with .animate() [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I'm trying to make my own video controls (as a learning exercise). I have the following code, which animates a progress bar when `#play` is pressed:

http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/TJB7r/

```
var video = $('video');
var duration;

$('#pause').on('click', function () {
    video[0].pause();
// lets pause the animation too!
});

$('#play').on('click', function () {
    video[0].play();
    duration = video[0].duration;
    $('#timer').animate({
        width: '100%'
    }, duration * 1000);
});
```

This then slowly increases the `#timer` width to `100%`. However, if I press pause, the timer still progresses.

What is the best way to pause `.animate()`, and then start again if required?

*Sidenote: I'm not sure if this is even the best method. Would something like setInterval() be better?*

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should use  < input type="range" >

You can add an "timeupdate" event listener on the video and update the value of the input, as the video plays.
Also add a "change" event listener to input, so you can jump through the video by clickng on the seek bar, etc.